# Selecting related hidden value based on selected check boxes

Tags: jquery

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I want to produce a string of user id's based on checkboxes being selected from a list.

My current code is:

```
<fieldset id="engineers" data-role="controlgroup">
@foreach (var item in Model.Maintenance_Team_List)
{
<label><input type="checkbox" name="Username"     />
@item.Username</label>@Html.Hidden("Booked_Engineer_ID",item.UserID)
}
</fieldset>
```

I have tried using jquery to check whether each username checkbox is selected or not. From there I am attempting to find its corresponding booked_engineer_id.

```
var listed = $('#Username input:checked').each(function () {
        $("#engineer_div").find('#Booked_Engineer_ID').text();
    });
```

This however doesn't seem to be selecting anything. I am looking for a simple output such as 23,10,11,1 where these values represent the values in the selected checkboxes booked_engineer_id hidden field.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can't repeat ID's in a page...they must be unique by definition....use class instaed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get value of input fields, you should use `val()` instead of `text()`.

But more important that your algorithm do strange things. I think you want to get something like this:

```
var listed = [];
$('input[name=Username]:checked').each(function (index, element) {
     var id = $(element).parent('label').next('input[name=Booked_Engineer_ID]').val();
     listed.push(id);
});
var simpleOutput = listed.join();
```

**UPDATE:**

In cases like yours I better suggest use data attributes instead of hidden fields:

```
<fieldset id="engineers" data-role="controlgroup">
@foreach (var item in Model.Maintenance_Team_List)
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-userId="@item.UserID" />
        @item.Username
    </label>
}
</fieldset>
```

and script:

```
var listed = [];
$('#engineers input:checked').each(function () {
     var id = $(this).data("userId");
     listed.push(id);
});
var simpleOutput = listed.join();
```

Comment: Thank you for the nudge in the right direction. I will post my edited version.

Comment: Great edit :) I hadn't even thought about using data attributes, nice and simple now!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the above code to work quite right but it prompted me to go in the right direction and produce the following:

```
var listed = [];
    $('input[name=Username]:checked').each(function () {

        var ID = $(this).parent().next().val();
        listed.push(ID)
    });

    var SimpleOutput = listed.join();
```

Love jquerys chaining.